# Convergence of a sequence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with a distribution function such that $n^t P(|X|>n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, for some $t>0$.

Then, I know that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$P(|X|>n) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{n^t} $$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq n_0$.

But, does the following stronger statement hold true?

For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$P(|X|>x) < \dfrac{\epsilon}{x^t} $$ for all $\boldsymbol {x\in \mathbb{R}}$, $x\geq n_0$.

Comment: No I have not. What I am asking is presented without a proof in a textbook in discussion of random variables

Comment: @Bey Sorry but Markov is really unrelated to the question asked here (which is pure real analysis, by the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^tP\{|X|>x\}\le \lceil x \rceil^tP\{|X|>\lfloor x\rfloor\}\le C\left(\lfloor x \rfloor^t +1 \right)P\{|X|>\lfloor x\rfloor\}$$

for some constant $C$ depending on $t$.